# Centralized Installer

Tags: linux, installation, cluster-computing

I am looking for an installer for my product. My requirement is that from one Node (Physical Machine) I should be able to install the software on multiple machines (Node). My product is a HA platform that needs to be installed on multiple Linux machines to form a cluster. Is there any installers that can do this free or paid. Currently we are developing on Linux, going forward we may need to support other Unix type OS.

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Package your product appropriately for the distribution (e.g. deb package) and use the standard management tools for the platform. Many simplicity-oriented people use

```
for node in $nodes; do ssh $node sudo apt-get install $package; done
```

and there is a host of cluster management software out there, one of which you are probably using.

Comment: *nod* Anything but a proper distro-specific package is going to make users want to hate you. Automatic installers are especially despised, there must be a way for the user to manually extract the files from whatever file you ship, if he so desired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an "installer" the way you use in Windows machines. However you can create packages depending on your system. For Debian like systems you can create .deb packages, and for Red Hat style you can create .rpm packages.
The way the packages are created is to specify a correct installation path for files and pre-install & post-install scripts to execute when you install the files. Also you can set dependencies on your package, so that if you require some important library, the deb/rpm installer won't install your package until the required library is installed.
Hope that makes sense with my broken English:)